# How to write data on influxDB cloud with api?

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2

I have problem with writing data to influxDB cloud using Postman. I could't find my data in my bucket. How to write data on influxDB cloud with api?[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5DpV.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the postman screenshot, it looks like the request was successful. 204 no content is the success code; see https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.1/api/#operation/PostWrite

The timestamp `1556813561098000000` in the lineprotocol you have is for `Thu May 02 2019 16:12:41 GMT+0000` which is ~3 years ago. If you are using a free account on cloud2, the buckets will only keep data for the last 30 days. Try a more recent timestamp or leave the timestamp out to get a timestamp of "now".